# Parsing VS2010 MSBuild vcxproj file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parsing, gcc, msbuild

I'm currently working on a console application that will pass a vcxproj file and compile it  using GCC.  Unfortunately, I've come up against a whole load of problems pretty much instantly.

I notice a bunch of directory shortcuts such as:

VCTargetsPath
VCInstallDir
SolutionDir
ProjectDir
UserRootDir

and so on.

Where does MSBuild get these values from?  I assumed they were environment variables set up for the MSBuild process (afterall known environment variables are addressed the same way, ie "$(...)").  This was a bad assumption so I'm left wondering exactly how I get at these.  Has anyone any idea on this?

Any info would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSBuild executable (and dependent DLLs) processes those properties the same way it processes any other property in the build file.  In this case, they're simply predefined properties that it looks for explicitly.

If you really want to dig into it, open up the `Microsoft.Build.dll` in Reflector and look for the `Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.AddGlobalProperties(...)` method to get an idea of how it's handling some of the well known properties.

As an additional note, make sure you fully navigate down Import directives and handle overwriting of property and item values with each Import.  There's a number of properties and items that are part of a Visual Studio build that are not always necessary for your code to compile correctly.

Comment: Cheers thats very interesting info.  I should point out, though, that I'm not really up for hooking MSBuild and inserting my own build method in.  I'm purely trying to parse the vcxproj files to generate my own code from those using GCC (rather than MSVC) ... I'm not entirely sure how the reflection information will help me there ... At the moment I am using an "NMAKE" build and passing through my own application that then parses the sln and vcproj and, ideally, generate me the GCC built code at the end.  The idea is that I can build from VSttudio other platforms including Android and MacOSX.

Comment: Interestingly it seems the only one that isn't define in advance is "VCTargetsPath" and a load of MSBuild specific ones.  The rest are, pretty much, found in the various .props files included. The MSBuild ones are defined in MSDN and the VCTargetsPath one is define in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that these are tied to Visual Studio macros: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm well aware of that.  But seeing as MSbuild can get hold of them .. that means i must be able to ... how?

Answer (score 2):

Some of them are defined by the location of your files

- SolutionDir - the directory containing the solution (.sln) file including this project
- ProjectDir - the directory containing the project file (.vcproj, .vcxproj)

Others are defined by the location of the MSVC install

- VCInstallDir - where the Visual C portion of Visual Studio is installed. ie. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC`

and so on, and would be internal to msbuild based on what you loaded.